# How to compare two files and concatenate an element to the resultant

Tags: java, string, compare, concatenation

If I am having 2 files

```
foo.txt
0 q 3 e Y
5 f i 6 h N

fooupdate.txt
f h
q e
```

I want to compare each line of `foo.txt` with `fooupdate.txt` inorder concatenate the last element of `foo.txt` to `fooupdate.txt`

ie `"0 q 3 e Y"` compare with `"f h"` and `"q e"` . If a similar string get detected then last element "Y" should be `concatenated` with `"q e"` ie `"q e Y"` and output should be stored in `updated.txt` as

```
f h N
q e Y
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You could store the contents of one file in a `List<String[]>` and do your comparison against each line of the other file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) in Java to read lines of the text files, and the [PrintWriter class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to create the updated.txt file.

In terms of an algorithm, one suggestion is you could use one file (fooupdate.txt) and compare each line of that file to each line of the other file (foo.txt).